# In, IPTables, whats the difference between these two rules?

Tags: linux, iptables

What the difference between these two or are they essentially the same thing?

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -s $EXTERNALNET -d $INTERNALNET -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -s $INTERNALNET -d $EXTERNALNET -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: At first blush, these look functionally identical, however I think further testing would be required to be certain.

Comment: They are not identical at all.

Comment: Ah, I see the error in my logic.  You're 100% correct, they'd not be identical, they'd instead be two sides of the same tcp connection, but not the same atomic packet.

Comment: @PeterGrace not even necessarily the same connection. Consider an outbound TCP connection to an arbitrary port (e.g. 80/tcp) with source port 22. It would be allowed, even though the intent is probably to only allow inbound connections to an SSH server.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Sneaky.  I admit defeat and reward you with 1 internet.

Answer (score 6):

The first rule accepts traffic being forwarded from `$EXTERNALNET` to `$INTERNALNET` with *destination* port 22/tcp.

The second rule accepts traffic being forwarded from `$INTERNALNET` to `$EXTERNALNET` with *source* port 22/tcp.

In a proper configuration of a stateful firewall like iptables, there should be no need for rules to allow traffic based on source port, since both directions of validly established TCP streams are allowed. Doing otherwise can lead to security holes--in this case, allowing all outbound traffic so long as it has a source port of 22/tcp.

With a non-stateful configuration, the example given is probably about the best that can be accomplished.

Comment: Note that iptables does not implicitly allow related traffic, that is configured by explicitly adding a "-m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" rule.  It only becomes stateful if you configure it as such.

Comment: That is why I emphasized "proper configuration."

Comment: Yes, but how is someone who is not used to setting up iptables supposed to know what "proper configuration" is?

Answer (score 1):

-s is source, and -d is destination, so these rules are in relation to traffic fowing in either direction.

the $INTERNALNET & $EXTERNALNET are variables, likely of a subnet or network range. I'm assuming this is from a bash script you got somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

```
--dport 22 ACCEPT
```

This directive tells the firewall to allow traffic destined for port 22 to pass through to your server.

```
--sport 22 ACCEPT
```

This directive tells the firewall to allow traffic sent from port 22 of outside machines to pass through to your server.

Comment: --sport is the source port on the packet.  Whether it's being sent from your machine or received on your machine is irrelevant, it's purely based on the source port as defined in the packet header.

Comment: You are entirely correct. Editing answer to reflect.

Comment: Also FORWARD refers to traffic going through the machine, not to or from it, and the host the packet came from may be either inside or outside the network.  The router itself is not involved.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the specific --dport ACCEPT and --sport ACCEPT directives.